# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence in keras using nltk ngram

Tags: python-3.x, hash, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import SimpleRNN
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np

text = open('eng.train').read().split()
words = []
tags_1 = []
tags_2 = []
for i in range(len(text)):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        words.append(text[i])
    if i % 4 == 1:
        tags_1.append(text[i])
    if i % 4 == 3:
        tags_2.append(text[i])

hashing_vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(decode_error = 'ignore', n_features = 2 **15)
X_v = hashing_vectorizer.fit_transform(words)

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y1 = label_encoder.fit_transform(tags_1)
y2 = label_encoder.fit_transform(tags_2)
y1 = np_utils.to_categorical(y1)
y2 = np_utils.to_categorical(y2)

import nltk
trigram_X = list(nltk.trigrams(X_v))
#trigram_X = list(trigram_X)
print(len(trigram_X))
X = numpy.array(trigram_X)
print(X.shape)

y = numpy.reshape(y1, (204567, 1, 46))
trigram_tags = list(nltk.trigrams(y))
#trigram_y = list(trigram_tags)
print (len(trigram_y))
target = numpy.array(trigram_y)
y = numpy.reshape(target, (204565, 3, 46))
X = numpy.reshape(X, (204565, 3, 1))

X_final = numpy.dstack((X, y))
print(X_final.shape)

X_input = X_final[: -1, :, :]
print(X_input.shape)

y_final = label_encoder.fit_transform(tags_1)
y_target = np_utils.to_categorical(y_final[3:])
print(y_target.shape)

from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.recurrent import SimpleRNN
```

Feature hashig is used here. Now the problem requires to give the generated hashed vector with a corresponding one hot encoded vector as the input. But the keras program is throwing the following error:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(100,input_shape = (X_input.shape[1], X_input.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(y_target.shape[1], activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_input, y_target, epochs = 20, batch_size = 200)


ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Please explain the reason for the error and a possible solution

**edit 1**

I have attached the full error stack as below

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4d9a4c1d9885> in <module>()
     62 model.add(Dense(y_target.shape[1], activation = 'softmax'))
     63 model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
---> 64 model.fit(X_input, y_target, epochs = 20, batch_size = 200)
     65 

/home/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    843                               class_weight=class_weight,
    844                               sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 845                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    846 
    847     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,

/home/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
   1483                               val_f=val_f, val_ins=val_ins, shuffle=shuffle,
   1484                               callback_metrics=callback_metrics,
-> 1485                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1486 
   1487     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None):

/home/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch)
   1138                 batch_logs['size'] = len(batch_ids)
   1139                 callbacks.on_batch_begin(batch_index, batch_logs)
-> 1140                 outs = f(ins_batch)
   1141                 if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1142                     outs = [outs]

/home/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2071         session = get_session()
   2072         updated = session.run(self.outputs + [self.updates_op],
-> 2073                               feed_dict=feed_dict)
   2074         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2075 

/home/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    787     try:
    788       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 789                          run_metadata_ptr)
    790       if run_metadata:
    791         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    966             feed_handles[subfeed_name] = subfeed_val
    967           else:
--> 968             np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
    969 
    970           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and

/home/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: @gionni I have posted the full error stack. I think that the error is somewhat related to the input shape of X_input